# What permissions should the /boot directory have?

Tags: permissions, security, directory

I have been reading a linux security paper that says we should only give root access to /boot directory. What does mean, in terms of permissions, 'only root access to /boot directory'?
If I set up my /boot to 700, a lot of files inside that dir which give permissions to root group and others wont be able to be accessed anymore? (in my case, 294 files has at least read permmission set to others). Should not /boot directory be set up at least to 755? but in this case, it's a  world access not only a root access?
Actually the question should be: are there some processes other than root which need access to /boot directory? how can I check that?
/var/log/boot.log does not give any answer to that
So far I understood that a computer starts that way: mother bios/efi  checks the hardware and looks for an mbr/boot media.Then it loads the boot loader and gives boot control to it. the boot loader then loads the kernel and gives boot control to it. The kernel starts services (among other things). Does all this performed by only root or by another user or another root group member as well?

The same idea goes for /boot/grub2 directory. This directory has got, by default, permissions set to 700:

```
ls -ld /boot/grub2 

drwx------. 4 root root 99 Aug 18 19:37 /boot/grub2
```

and there are numerous files in this dir:

```
find /boot/grub2 -type f | wc -l 

282
```

but only 2 of them are not accessible to others

```
find /boot/grub2 -type f ! -perm /007 -printf '%y %u %g %m %p\n'

f root root 600 /boot/grub2/grubenv

f root root 600 /boot/grub2/user.cfg
```

so why set /boot/grub2 up to 700 which is incoherent in view of permissions that have been set up inside that directory ?

Tell me what I have missed there please.

Thanx folks!

Answer (score 2):

If your set `/boot/grub2` to `700` no files under it regardless of their permissions will be accessible for normal users. No files under this directory are read or used during or after boot. `user.cfg` contains boot passwords, so protecting this file makes sense but **only** for local users. In short, I see no reason to override what your distro sets for you by default.

A more important directory is `/boot/efi` which is set to `700` because it is normally a FAT partition which by default allows everyone to alter files, and you wouldn't want unprivileged users to meddle with your UEFI boot files.

You can set `/boot` to `755` or `700` but changing your distro defaults makes zero sense. There are no special files right under this directory which local user could read and gain root access. `vmlinuz` and `initrd` can be trivially accessed using your package manager or your distro public files.

In short you're obsessing over a security issue which you've made up and which doesn't exist.

Comment: .@Artem: 1- "If your set /boot/grub2 to 700 ... for normal users." -> this is precisely the purpose of my post. 2- "/boot/efi which is set to 700" -> on my centos 8, by default, it's 755   3-  there is a big difference between /boot set to 700 and 755: some Security experts say : only user root should have access to /boot; some malwares use /boot to build some kernel exploits. Security experts even say that /boot could be mounted as noauto among other options.

Comment: https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/en/guide/configuration-recommendations-of-a-gnulinux-system/

Comment: *some malwares use /boot to build some kernel exploits.* I've already addressed this in my post. Speaking of "security" "experts": please show me successful hacks using wide open (`755`) `/boot`. In short, you refuse to read, you refuse to understand and you pay attention to random people who call themselves "security experts".

Comment: If your `/boot/efi` is set to 755, that could an issue - please submit a bug report.

Comment: I have to agree with @ArtemS.Tashkinov here, even with `755` perms on `/boot`, not much harm (if any) can be caused by any user other than `root`. If someone did manage to get root access, this would probably be the least of one's worries.

Comment: .@Artem: Thank you for you help but please help someone else.

Comment: You haven't marked your question solved, so it might be possible someone else will answer it since you're seemingly not content with my answer and you trust some random "security" experts from the net, who you apparently cannot quote for some reasons. Sorry for not delivering the answer you're looking for and which is **"not to trust what Linux distros have been doing for tens of years"** because you are the only person in the world who sees the issue. Not that anyone has been hacked due to this "issue", it shouldn't concern you. Conspiracies are interesting but very rarely fruitful.

Comment: One other thing: I've been managing tens of Linux servers for almost two decades now and not a single one has been hacked due to `755` applied to `/boot`. If a hacker has access to shell your boot directory permissions will be the absolute least of your concerns. Hackers normally gain access via vulnerabilities in software (most common ones are listed here, yay, quotes https://cwe.mitre.org/top25/archive/2021/2021_cwe_top25.html ) or improperly set authentication schemes. "Incorrect Default Permissions" are on the list but 755/644 user:group root:root is not what could be deemed incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I won't delete the answer because I stand by it despite you downvoting it. You don't have the expertise to downvote it even though you dislike it. Lastly if you believe you've unearthed a critical vulnerability in probably **all** Linux distros, you could report it to some large company like e.g. Google, Facebook or Netflix (each of them employing thousands of Linux servers) and claim a hefty reward. Strangely no one has done it before.

Comment: .@Artem: You answer addresses nothing; there is no explanation and it looks like you did not read carefuly or understood my post. Before answering check the link I gave, I think the source is good enough.

Comment: *"There are no special files right under this directory which local user could read and gain root access. vmlinuz and initrd can be trivially accessed using your package manager or your distro public files."* It's **you** who didn't bother to read anything that I posted unfortunately. Again, **Lastly if you believe you've unearthed a critical vulnerability in probably all Linux distros, you could report it to some large company like e.g. Google, Facebook or Netflix (each of them employing thousands of Linux servers) and claim a hefty reward.**